# Panda Dataframe adding more columns to .csv when editing certain values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am using Panda Dataframe to store some information for my code. In my code,

Initial State of csv:

```
...............
ID,Name

...............
```

Adding Data into dataframe:

```
name_desc = {"ID": 23523223, "Name": BlahBlah}  
df = df.append(name_desc, ignore_index=True)
```

This was my panda dataframe upon creating the database:

```
....................
,ID,Name
0,23523223,BlahBlah
....................
```

Below is my code that searches through the ID column to locate the row with the stated ID (name_desc["ID"]).

```
df.loc[df["ID"] == name_desc["ID"], "Name"] = name_desc["Name"]
```

The problem I encountered was after I have edited the name, I get a resultant db that looks like:

```
................................
   Unnamed: 0         ID   Name
0           0   23523223  BlahBlah
................................
```

If I continously execute:

```
df.loc[df["ID"] == name_desc["ID"], "Name"] = name_desc["Name"]
```

I get this db:

```
..................................    
,Unnamed: 0,Unnamed: 0.1,ID,Name
0,0,0,235283335,Dinese
..................................
```

I can't figure out why I have extra columns being added in the front of my database as I make edits.

Comment: I assume BlahBlah is a string. Are you sure your df is created in this way? Because from what I can see there, right after the creation of the df you already have 3 columns (there is a comma before ID) which does not make sense with the data you inserted in name_desc. Are you sure?

Comment: Try to check the columns you have in you df after the creation using `print(df.columns)`

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a problem that is related to the df creation. The example you provided here does not return what you are showing:

```
BlahBlah = 'foo'
name_desc = {"ID": 23523223, "Name": BlahBlah}  
df = pd.DataFrame(data=name_desc, index=[0])

print(df.columns) # it returns an Index(['ID', 'Name'], dtype='object')
print(len(df.columns)) # it returns 2, the number of your df columns
```

If you can, try to find what instruction adds the extra column to your code. Otherwise you can remove the column using **drop** and remove the column with '' as name. **inplace** is used to actually modify the dataframe. if inplace is not added, you just create a view of the dataframe without actually modifying it:

```
df.drop(columns = [''], inplace = True)
```

Finally, I post in the following the full example. My assumption is that your df is somehow created with the empty column at the beginnig, so I also add it in the dictionary:

```
BlahBlah = 'foo'
name_desc = {'':'',"ID": 23523223, "Name": BlahBlah}  # I added an empty column 
df = pd.DataFrame(data=name_desc, index = [0])

print(df.columns) # Index(['', 'ID', 'Name'], dtype='object')

df.drop(columns = [''],inplace = True)
df.loc[df["ID"] == name_desc["ID"], "Name"] = name_desc["Name"]

print(df.columns) # Index(['ID', 'Name'], dtype='object')
```

Comment: I have made an edit to my question, hopefully it is clearer. Sorry for the unclear question.